# WARNING: The conversion of web application and most of the users to Claims mode

Tags: authentication, migration

I am migrating from SP2010 to SP2013 farm. In the old farm web applications are using Window Classic mode. I was told to follow the procedure here ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985%28v=office.15%29.aspx)). Hence I followed the section "Convert SharePoint 2010 Products classic-mode web applications to SharePoint 2013 claims-based web applications"

My first question is, why I need to perform conversion steps? I am not feeling comfortable because my users can login to new farm without perform above steps.

In order to follow best practice, I followed and when I run `Convert-SPWebApplication –Identity yourWebAppUrl –To Claims -RetainPermissions`

It returnes warning:

```
WARNING: The conversion of web application and most of the users to Claims mode
 is completed. However, one or more users could not be converted to Claims
mode. Refer to the ULS logs for the details. For the troubleshooting tips refer
 to the http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236943 article.
```

It even not giving me the correlection number so I am unable to track what went wrong. However I can login to the site with several users (I have hundred users and unable to check 1 by 1)

My second question is, do I need to worry about the warning?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question # 1** Claims-based authentication is an essential component to enable the advanced functionality of SharePoint 2013.Due to the widespread use of claim-based authentication for user authentication, server-to-server authentication, and app authentication, we recommend claims-based authentication for all web applications and zones of a SharePoint 2013 farm.  When you use claims-based authentication, all supported authentication methods are available for your web applications and you can take advantage of new features and scenarios in SharePoint 2013 that use server-to-server authentication and app authentication.\
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350(v=office.15).aspx#cba](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350%28v=office.15%29.aspx#cba)

**Question # 2**  Most probably these are user who are no more part of your orginzation but still present in the User Information List. You can collect logs for the durtion when you ran the command. Using merge-splogfile and then examine it. You will see all the user which were not converted.

Comment: After tracking the log, I found some users are not belonging to our company exist in user information list. (it is some users like test.com/user1 exist I guess the vendor built a test domain and access SP before). Hence question #2 is the issue. Thanks!